# Will my tourist visa be accepted if I have 2 months of bank statements?

Tags: visas, japan, proof-provenance-of-funds

Will my visa be accepted if I have 2 months of bank statements, with enough money to travel to Japan as a tourist? Or would I need someone else to sponsor my trip?

Comment: Bank statements are not just about having money, they are about having a stable job to return to.

Comment: And they need to show that you own the money, not have borrowed it to apply for the visa.

Comment: Do the Japanese Immigration rules *require* a sponsor? How long is your trip? What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what country you come from, but generally you need to show that you have enough money to sustain yourself for the duration of your stay in Japan, and that this is money which has sat in your account as personal savings for three months. If the money is coming from a third person, then you need to provide information about the third person and why/how he/she is providing the money to you.

If you have a sponsor then it is easier to obtain a visa because it will show that someone in Japan can vouch for you, but remember that the sponsor may need to show that he/she is capable of supporting you as well.

So yes it is required to provide three months bank statements and advisable to obtain a sponsor.